# amazon SES bounce and complaint configuration

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-sns, amazon-ses

I don't receive any bounce and complaint notification, when I give a wrong email id or mark the mail as spam (receiving delivery notification). But i receive a notification for amazon test simulator mail id's ? Can anyone help me out to solve this problem?

Comment: How long has it been? Bounce and complaint notifications can be delayed by several hours.  Also, testing by flagging your own email as spam is a bad idea.  If the simulator works, then real events should also work.

Comment: It's been one day.

Comment: I have recieved bounce notification. but the complaint notification is not working. is this an  ISP authentication problem ?

Comment: Probably not an ISP "authentication" problem but rather the fact that complaint notifications are not part of SMTP itself, like bounces are.  They're an entirely different thing, requiring voluntary participation from email service providers.

Answer (score 1):

**Regarding hardbounce and complaints Delay**

The hardbounce and complaint notifications can get delayed. And the delay can be as long as 14 hours. 
Following is the sample text that we received after approx 14 hours when attempted at ddfd@sas

```
Remote Server returned '< #4.4.7 smtp; 554 4.4.7 Message expired: unable to deliver in 840 minutes.<421 4.4.0 Unable to lookup DNS for sas>>'
```

The quickest and easiest way to test hardbounces is use something very random like 'jhdfggdfgdfghaaaaa@bbbbbbbkjfghjkjfhgfgf.JJJJJJ'

**Regarding complaints**

You do not get the complaint notifications from all the providers, only the ones that have FBL (Feed Back Look). To know more about FBL [click here](https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/ses/email-definitions-feedback-loops/)

Following is an extract from that page

> Do all ISPs support feedback loops? Unfortunately, no. If you are curious, review the [Word to the Wise Delivery Wiki](http://wiki.wordtothewise.com/ISP_Summary_Information) for a relatively up-to-date list.

The quickest and easiest way to test complaints is use @yahoo domain. We found that we get spam notifications from them pretty quickly

Comment: Did you receive the hardbounces as well?